# How can I store HTML code in a Postgresql DB table field?

Tags: php, html, postgresql

I get a large and vary dynamic XML data feed (200+ categories and 3500+ products that is 11+ MB) to CRUD my DB.  The problem is, there is HTML code embedded in the long description field (.e.g. links to a video and player settings as well as page layout. YES, I know, a programming no no - should be done with CSS - but it is there anyhow.  When creating the database table HTML is not an option.  I am using PHP and PostgreSQL on a WAPP stack.  How can I get around this problem?

Comment: use `TEXT` as the column type.

Answer (score 23):

You could try using a `TEXT` field and dump the `HTML` there.

Additionally, `PostgreSQL` has in-built automatic [compression](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-toast.html) for `TEXT` fields!