# psycopg2 - List index out of range for html (large string) field

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, mogrify

I have a webcrawler that should save/insert the html page content to a PostgreSQL Database with some other meta data fields.

When inserting the html content field using `mogrify` I'll get the error message `List index out of range`. If I use a static dummy text for the html content e.g. "Hello World ö ü ä ß" (I am dealing with a german character set) the insert works fine.

This is my function:

```
def batch_insert(df, table, no_cols, conn=None, upsert_qry=""):
    """
    Using cursor.mogrify() to build the bulk insert query
    then cursor.execute() to execute the query
    """
    if conn is None:
        conn = get_connection()

    col_str = "(" + (no_cols-1)*"%s," + "%s)"
    # Create a list of tuples from the dataframe values
    tuples = [tuple(x) for x in df.to_numpy()]
    # Comma-separated dataframe columns
    cols = ','.join(list(df.columns))
    # SQL quert to execute
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    values = [cursor.mogrify(col_str, tup).decode('utf8') for tup in tuples]

    query = "INSERT INTO %s(%s) VALUES " % (table, cols) + ",".join(values) + upsert_qry
        #" ON CONFLICT (hk_portal_pid) DO UPDATE SET crawled_last=" + str(datetime.now())
        
    try:
        cursor.execute(query, tuples)
        conn.commit()
    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        print("Error: %s" % error)
        conn.rollback()
        cursor.close()
        return 1
    print("execute_mogrify() done")
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
```

The postgres column field is declared as `text` as suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35114928/how-can-i-store-html-code-in-a-postgresql-db-table-field). The html content in my case has an average length of 40.000 characters, so there shouldn't be any storage issues.

I also checked if the the generated tuple in the function gets splitted for the html content field because of escape characters etc.. But this doesn't seem to be the case.

```
>>>>[len(a) for a in tuples]
    [9, 9, 9, 9] # 4 rows / 9 columns
```

Data type for the 8th column (page_content) is string:

```
>>>>type(tuples[0][7])
<class 'str'>
```

Target table for batch insert:

```
CREATE TABLE public.as_portal_parent_content (
    hk_page varchar(100) NULL,
    hk_offer varchar(100) NULL,
    portal_id varchar(3) NULL,
    pid varchar(10) null,
    page_category varchar(30) null,
    page_link bpchar(300) null,
    status varchar(3) null,
    page_content text null,
    last_crawled timestamp null
);
```

Any help much appreciated!

**Added/Edit:**

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/project/playground.py", line 5, in <module>
    test.save_to_db(table='as_portal_parent_content')
  File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/project/util/crawl.py", line 163, in save_to_db
    batch_insert(self.df, table)
  File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/project/util/db.py", line 60, in batch_insert
    cursor.execute(query, tuples)
IndexError: list index out of range

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Why do you need `no_cols` if you can determine no. of columns using `df.colums`? Are they supposed to be different?

Comment: Thanks for spotting this unnecessary argument. `no_cols` are the same. However, I receive the same error...

Comment: Can you add the traceback?

Comment: Added the traceback. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use `tuples` in `cursor.execute(query, tuples)`.
When you use [`mogrify`](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.mogrify), you are basically generating the after-VALUES part of the sql query. So, there's no need to pass query parameters(`tuples` in your case) to `cur.execute` again.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. But strange that it worked with the `tuples` argument for a dummy content field.

Comment: Beacuse you didn't use `mogrify` with dummy data?

Comment: I did. The only difference was that the passed argument `df` did not had the real html content but dummy content as a value instead. The `mogrify` batch insert worked with dummy data for the page_content field. However, just happy that it does work now =)

Comment: I had the same phenomenon. I noticed that the code works on smaller datasets, and fails on larger ones. I don't know the reason why.

Comment: @andexte Does it fail with a different error when using large datasets?

Comment: The error I got is "list index out of range". So this is the same. @Shiva, your solution works for me as well!